# Fixing my table notes

Tags: tablenotes

I am still learning the ropes with Latex so forgive me if this is a straight forward question. I would like to have table notes below my table. However, the default is to center the table notes. I have figured out that to move it to the left I need to use `[flushleft]` but this removes the ability to have new lines even if I use a double backslash (`\\`). When I use `[para,flushleft]` if has weird spacing to cover the entire line. How do I get the notes to begin on the left, move onto a new line when I need it to and not have weird spacing all at the same time?

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{documentclass}
        \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \caption{First Stage Results}\label{First Stage results}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{9}{c}}
    \hline\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Public Sector Education in \$1,000}} \\
                        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}         \\
    \hline
    Students In Gov Schools&       0.231\sym{***}&                     &       0.544\sym{***}&                     &       0.258         &      -0.213         &      -0.702         &                     &      -0.744         \\
                        &      (9.10)         &                     &      (3.45)         &                     &      (0.86)         &     (-0.42)         &     (-0.63)         &                     &     (-0.70)         \\
    [1em]
    Government Schools  &                     &       81.45\sym{***}&      -115.3         &      -675.7\sym{*}  &                     &      -763.9         &                     &       121.6         &       153.9         \\
                        &                     &      (7.70)         &     (-1.93)         &     (-2.09)         &                     &     (-1.61)         &                     &      (0.50)         &      (0.69)         \\
    [1em]
    Percentage Growth Working Age&                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &    -12234.3         &    -10629.6         &    -12852.3         \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &     (-0.83)         &     (-0.75)         &     (-0.85)         \\
    [1em]
    Private Education Construction&                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &       0.873\sym{**} &       0.883\sym{**} &       0.869\sym{**} \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (3.37)         &      (3.11)         &      (3.30)         \\
    [1em]
    Political Party     &                     &                     &                   &                     &                     &                     &      4009.8         &     -1272.7         &      3351.3         \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (0.14)         &     (-0.05)         &      (0.12)         \\
    [1em]
    Exports to China         &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &       3.168         &       2.542         &       2.696         \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (0.61)         &      (0.54)         &      (0.55)         \\
    [1em]
    Young-age Workers   &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &       1.964         &       2.131         &       2.018         \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (0.91)         &      (0.98)         &      (0.92)         \\
    [1em]
    Mid-age workers     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      -0.593         &      -0.787         &      -0.588         \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &     (-0.67)         &     (-0.98)         &     (-0.67)         \\
    [1em]
    Old-age workers     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      -0.250         &      -0.248         &      -0.234         \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &     (-0.53)         &     (-0.52)         &     (-0.51)         \\
    [1em]
    Building The Education Revolution&                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &     65553.2\sym{*}  &     69193.6\sym{*}  &     65809.6\sym{*}  \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (2.44)         &      (2.26)         &      (2.46)         \\
    \hline Fixed Effects & No & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
    Observations        &         136         &         136         &         136         &         136         &         136         &         136         &         128         &         128         &         128         \\ Kleibergen–Paap F & 82.75 & 59.36 & 109.27 & 4.37 & 0.74 & 1.71 & 0.40 & 0.25 & 1.50 \\
    \hline\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
    \small
    \textbf{Notes:} Fixed effects cover both state and time. Education construction is adjusted for inflation \\ \textit{t} statistics in parentheses\\ \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)\\
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{table}

\end{documentclass}
```

Comment: tables notes are not centred by default. Can you show some test document that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I edited my question to include the code I used. I wasn't sure how to get it on separate lines so forgive it all being on the same line.

Comment: Could you please add a small compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe?

Comment: How do I copy my code in without it ending up like it does now?

Comment: @AsafCohen: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @AsafCohen: Could you please make the code snippet compilable by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages? Also I' d recommend to not use `adjustbox` on a table as it will lead to inconsistent and illegibly small font sizes.

Comment: Is it ok now @leandriis?

Comment: @AsafCohen: The `documentclass` still seems to be missing. Also `float` and `floatrow` are not compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible table looks:

[image]
(red lines indicate text borders)

I wouldn't use `adjustbox` for reducing table width. With it the control on fonts ia lost. I would rather redesign table:

- Define width of the first table column. If cells contents in this column are wider than column width, it will break into two line. By this the table width is significant reduced.
- Cells' contents in the first column I would put into `multirow` environment
  -Reduce `\tabcolsep` to `0pt` and than insert space between columns determined by macro `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`.
- Select smaller font size. It seems that `\small` is appropriate size (your document's page layout is unknown).
- For horizontal rules use rules from the `booktabs package
- Sspace between row's groups I wouldd use `\addlinespace` provided by the `booktabs` package

  ```
  \documentclass{article}  
  \usepackage{geometry}                  % new
  \usepackage{booktabs, multirow}        % new
  \usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}% new

  \begin{document}
          \begin{table}[ht]
  \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{First Stage Results}\label{First Stage results}
      \small
      \centering
      \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
      \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                         p{10em}
                    *{9}{c}
                                  }
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Public Sector Education in \$1,000}} \\
      \cmidrule{2-10}
      &{(1)}              & {(2)}             & {(3)}             & {(4)}
      & {(5)}             & {(6)}             & {(7)}             & {(8)}
      & {(9)}             \\
      \midrule
  \multirow{2}{=}{Students \\ Gov Schools}
      & 0.231\tnote{***}  &                   & 0.544\tnote{***}  &
      & 0.258             & -0.213            & -0.702            &
      &-0.744             \\
      & (9.10)            &                   & (3.45)            &
      & (0.86)            & (0.42)            & (0.63)            &
      & (0.70)            \\
      \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}{=}{Government Schools}
      &                   & 81.45\tnote{***}  & -115.3            & -675.7\tnote{*}
      &                   & -763.9            &                   &  121.6
      & 153.9             \\
      &                   & (7.70)            & (1.93)            & (2.09)
      &                   & (1.61)       &                        & (0.50)
      & (0.69)            \\
      \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}{=}{Percentage Growth Working Age}
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & -12234.3          & -10629.6
      & {-12852.3}        \\

      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & (0.83)            & (0.75)
      & (0.85)            \\
      \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}{=}{Private Education Construction}
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & 0.873\tnote{**}   & 0.883\tnote{**}
      & 0.869\tnote{**}   \\
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & (3.37)            & (3.11)
      & (3.30)            \\
      \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}{=}{Political Party}
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & {4009.8}          &{-1272.7}
      & {3351.3}          \\
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & (0.14)            & (0.05)
      & (0.12)            \\
      \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}{=}{Exports to China}
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & 3.168             & 2.542
      & 2.696             \\
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & 0.61)             & (0.54)
      & (0.55)            \\
      \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}{=}{Young-age Workers}
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & 1.964             & 2.131
      & 2.018             \\
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & (0.91)            & (0.98)
      & (0.92)            \\
      \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}{=}{Mid-age workers}
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & -0.593            & -0.787
      & -0.588            \\
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & (0.67)            & (0.98)
      & (0.67)       \\
      \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}{=}{Old-age workers}
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & -0.250            & -0.248
      & -0.234            \\
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & (0.53)            & (0.52)
      & (0.51)       \\
      \addlinespace
  \multirow{2}{=}{Building The Education Revolution}
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & 65553.2\tnote{*}  & 69193.6\tnote{*}
      & {65809.6}\tnote{*}    \\
      &                   &                   &                   &
      &                   &                   & (2.44)            & (2.26)
      & (2.46)            \\
      \midrule
  Fixed Effects
      & No    & No    & No        & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \\
  Observations
      & 136   & 136   & 136       & 136   & 136   & 136   & 128   & 128   & 128 \\
  Kleibergen–Paap F
      & 82.75 & 59.36 & 109.27    & 4.37  & 0.74  & 1.71  & 0.40  & 0.25  & 1.50 \\
      \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
      \end{tabular*}
      \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
      \footnotesize
      \raggedright
  \note{ Fixed effects cover both state and time. Education construction is adjusted for inflation.}

  \item{$t$} statistics are in parentheses

  \item{*}    \(p<0.05\),
  \item{**}   \(p<0.01\),
  \item{***}  \(p<0.001\)
      \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
      \end{table}
  \end{document}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually not using any table notes, so I would simply place your text below the tabular:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
%\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
        \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \caption{First Stage Results}\label{First Stage results}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{9}{c}}
    \hline\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{Public Sector Education in \$1,000}} \\
                        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(9)}         \\
    \hline
    Students In Gov Schools&       0.231\sym{***}&                     &       0.544\sym{***}&                     &       0.258         &      -0.213         &      -0.702         &                     &      -0.744         \\
                        &      (9.10)         &                     &      (3.45)         &                     &      (0.86)         &     (-0.42)         &     (-0.63)         &                     &     (-0.70)         \\
    [1em]
    Government Schools  &                     &       81.45\sym{***}&      -115.3         &      -675.7\sym{*}  &                     &      -763.9         &                     &       121.6         &       153.9         \\
                        &                     &      (7.70)         &     (-1.93)         &     (-2.09)         &                     &     (-1.61)         &                     &      (0.50)         &      (0.69)         \\
    [1em]
    Percentage Growth Working Age&                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &    -12234.3         &    -10629.6         &    -12852.3         \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &     (-0.83)         &     (-0.75)         &     (-0.85)         \\
    [1em]
    Private Education Construction&                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &       0.873\sym{**} &       0.883\sym{**} &       0.869\sym{**} \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (3.37)         &      (3.11)         &      (3.30)         \\
    [1em]
    Political Party     &                     &                     &                   &                     &                     &                     &      4009.8         &     -1272.7         &      3351.3         \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (0.14)         &     (-0.05)         &      (0.12)         \\
    [1em]
    Exports to China         &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &       3.168         &       2.542         &       2.696         \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (0.61)         &      (0.54)         &      (0.55)         \\
    [1em]
    Young-age Workers   &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &       1.964         &       2.131         &       2.018         \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (0.91)         &      (0.98)         &      (0.92)         \\
    [1em]
    Mid-age workers     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      -0.593         &      -0.787         &      -0.588         \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &     (-0.67)         &     (-0.98)         &     (-0.67)         \\
    [1em]
    Old-age workers     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      -0.250         &      -0.248         &      -0.234         \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &     (-0.53)         &     (-0.52)         &     (-0.51)         \\
    [1em]
    Building The Education Revolution&                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &     65553.2\sym{*}  &     69193.6\sym{*}  &     65809.6\sym{*}  \\
                        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &      (2.44)         &      (2.26)         &      (2.46)         \\
    \hline Fixed Effects & No & No & No & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
    Observations        &         136         &         136         &         136         &         136         &         136         &         136         &         128         &         128         &         128         \\ Kleibergen–Paap F & 82.75 & 59.36 & 109.27 & 4.37 & 0.74 & 1.71 & 0.40 & 0.25 & 1.50 \\
    \hline\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
%    \begin{tablenotes}[para]
        \flushleft
    \small
    \textbf{Notes:} Fixed effects cover both state and time. Education construction is adjusted for inflation \\ \textit{t} statistics in parentheses\\ \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)\\
%    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

(I had to remove a few lines about `floatrow` because it caused error message and invent a documentclass, because there was no one in the question)

[image]